# Binary search tree, coding issue

Tags: binary-search-tree

For some weird reason my BST tree isn't really working out as expected, this is the code that I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

//Creating the main structure of the main BST Tree
struct treeNode{
    int key; //The key of the node
    struct treeNode *leftChild; //The left child of the node
    struct treeNode *rightChild; //The right child of the node
    struct treeNode *parent; //The parent of the node
};

//Function for implementing and creating a new node in the BST
struct treeNode* newNode(int x){
    struct treeNode *n;
    n = malloc(sizeof(struct treeNode));
    n->key = x;
    n->leftChild = NULL;
    n->rightChild = NULL;
    n->parent = NULL;

    return n;

}

//Function for finding the minimun value in a treeNode
struct treeNode* BSTTreeMin(struct treeNode *root){
    
    if(root->leftChild == NULL){
        return root; //if the left child is nil, return the root
    }
    else{
        return BSTTreeMin(root->leftChild); //otherwise we repeform the same operation on the left child
    }
}

//Function for searching a specific node in the BST
struct treeNode* BSTTreeSearch(struct treeNode *root,int x){
    if(root == NULL || root->key == x){
        return root; //if root corresponds to key then the element x is found 
    }
    if(x < root->key){
        return BSTTreeSearch(root->leftChild, x); // in the case where the element x is smaller than root-->key then it searches the left child
    }
    else{
        return BSTTreeSearch(root->rightChild, x);// in the opposite case, it searches the right child
    }
}

//function for inserting a new key in the BST
struct treeNode* BSTTreeInsert(struct treeNode *root, struct treeNode *z){
    struct treeNode *y = NULL;
    struct treeNode *x = root;
    while(x != NULL){
        y = x;
        if(z->key <= x->key){
            x = x->leftChild;
        }
        else{
            x = x->rightChild;
        }
    }
    z->parent = y;
    if(y == NULL){
        root = z;
    }
    else if(root != NULL && z->key <= y->key){
        y->leftChild = z;
    }
    else{
        y->rightChild = z;
    }
}

struct treeNode* BSTTreeTransplant(struct treeNode *root, struct treeNode *u, struct treeNode *v){
    if(u->parent == NULL){
        root = v;
    }
    else if(u == u->parent->leftChild){
        u->parent->leftChild = v;
    }
    else{
        u->parent->rightChild = v;
    }
    if(v != NULL){
        v->parent = u->parent;
    }
}
//function for delete a node in a BST
struct treeNode* BSTTreeDelete(struct treeNode *root, struct treeNode *z){
    if(z->leftChild == NULL){
        BSTTreeTransplant(root, z, z->rightChild);
    }
    else if(z->rightChild == NULL){
        BSTTreeTransplant(root, z, z->leftChild);
    }
    else{
        struct treeNode *y = BSTTreeMin(z->rightChild);
        if(y->parent != z){
            BSTTreeTransplant(root, y, y->rightChild);
            y->rightChild = z->rightChild;
            y->rightChild->parent = y;
        }
        BSTTreeTransplant(root, z, y);
        y->leftChild = z->leftChild;
        y->leftChild->parent = y;
    }
}

//Function for emptying a BST
void BSTTreeDeallocate(struct treeNode *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    BSTTreeDeallocate(root->leftChild);
    BSTTreeDeallocate(root->rightChild);
    free(root);
}

//function that checks if the Bst is valid (antagonistic function)
int isValidBstHelper(struct treeNode *root, int low, int high) {
    return root == NULL || 
        (root->key >= low && root->key <= high &&
         isValidBstHelper(root->leftChild, low, root->key) &&
         isValidBstHelper(root->rightChild, root->key, high)); 
}

//function that initiate the validity check of the Bst
int isValidBst(struct treeNode *root) {
    return isValidBstHelper(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
}

//Main experiment function for this program, calculating the time for inserting, deleting and searching nodes in our BST
double SingleExperiment(int max_keys,double max_search,double max_delete,int max_instances){
    double t_tot = 0;
    int i;
    int key;
    double search;
    double delete;

    for(i = 1; i <= max_instances; i++){
        clock_t start_t, end_t;
        
        srand(0);
        struct treeNode *root;
        root = newNode(rand()); // Initializing the root of the tree

        struct treeNode *i = newNode(rand());
        struct treeNode *d = newNode(rand());

        start_t = clock();
        for(key = 1; key <= max_keys; key++){
            BSTTreeInsert(root,i); //Starting with the insertion of the nodes
        }
        for(search = 1; search <= max_search; search++){
            BSTTreeSearch(root, rand()); //Following by the searching of the nodes
        }
        for(delete = 1; delete <= max_delete; delete++){
            BSTTreeDelete(root, d); //Finally, the deletion of the nodes
        }

        end_t = clock();
        double t_elapsed = (double)(end_t - start_t); //Calculation of the time elapased
        t_tot += t_elapsed; //Adding the time to the total time

        //inorder(root); //checks if the BST is in order --> prints an ordered array

        //Checking if the Bst is valid
        if (isValidBst(root)) {
            printf("The tree is a valid BST \n");
        } else {
            printf("The tree is NOT a valid BST \n");
        }

        BSTTreeDeallocate(root); //Emptying the tree

    }
    return t_tot/max_keys; //Returning the average time
}

//main function (represents the experiment function)
int main(void){ 
    int min_keys = 5;
    int max_keys = 10;
    int max_instances = 5;
    int percentage_search = 60;
    int keys;
    int seed = 0;
    //setting up the main parameters for the experiment

    printf("Binary Search Tree \n");
    for(keys = min_keys; keys <= max_keys; keys = keys +1){
        srand(seed);
        double max_search = keys * percentage_search / 100;
        double max_delete = keys - max_search;

        double time = SingleExperiment(keys,max_search,max_delete,max_instances);
        printf("%d %f\n",keys,time);//printing the time associate to each key value
        
        seed = seed +1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

the outcome should be "the tree is valid" for every iteration and the total time for every single key number. Whenever I launch the program, it only prints out "Binary Search Tree" and nothing else.
Could you please kindly help me out?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: There are many problems with this code. You can certainly pinpoint through debugging where things can go wrong. Please do the effort of debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem occurs in this loop:

```
    for(key = 1; key <= max_keys; key++){
        BSTTreeInsert(root,i);
    }
```

Ignoring that `i` is a bad choice as a variable name for a node (it is already used as the loop variable), this will insert the *same* node repeatedly. This means that the second iteration of this loop will insert a node that is already in the tree. This will make the node its own child (a self-reference). As a consequence, the third iteration of this loop, will never reach a leaf in the tree, as it keeps following that self-reference, running in circles.

The quick fix is to insert *new* nodes in each iteration:

```
    for(key = 1; key <= max_keys; key++){
        BSTTreeInsert(root, newNode(rand());
    }
```

Now, this fixes your problem, but still I'd like to remark that the rest of the experiment code is not really doing much useful:

- `BSTTreeSearch` is very, very likely to be called with values that do not occur in the tree, and it is not tested whether indeed the function returns the expected result. But then there should also be *positive* tests -- to see if values that *are* in the tree, are actually found.
- `BSTTreeDelete` is called repeatedly with the *same* node. Moreover, this node was never inserted in the tree, so these calls will never remove any node from the tree.

You might want to improve on that -- but it is out of the scope of your question.